# How can publish my bootstrap created table ( huge amount of data) on my word-press theme?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I created a bootstrap table which is interactive with data-tables also.I use jquery too.How can i publish this table on my word-press table 
(code is working ).Thank you...

I just want to publish this table on word press website which is consists of huge amount of pages.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add custom html code into your wordpress site probably the best approach is a custom template : https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/
Add the following to a new .php file into your template folder with this :

```
<?php /* Template Name: My Template */ ?>
```

Paste you custom html after it.

Then open WP admin and create a new Page.

Select My Template from the template setting

Save and view